# Set all values to 0 except for cells containing strings in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range ("C55:C350") that contains headers "Indexation" and percentage "5%" for example.

I want to add a button in my sheet that will put all the indexation cells to 0 while keeping the header...

I thought about just selecting the range that need to be changed but it would be time consuming and not handy if my file was about to change (which it will probably do in the future)...

Can someone give me a hand with this?

Comment: Loop through the cells, validate their content and write `0` to them? Can you please show us the code you have so far and explain the exact problem you have with it?

Comment: As mentionned, I am new to this so struggling a bit, the only lines I have tried to write for this are:

Sub SetAllMediaValueToZero()
If Not IsEmpty(Range("C55:C68").Value) Then
Range("C55:C80").Value = 0
End If
End Sub

Comment: Better to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73963004/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the header in C55 and the data in C56:C350, all on Sheet1. You could use

```
Sheet1.Range("C56:C350").Value = 0
```

That will set the value of every cell in that range to zero. If you're not sure how many rows you will have, but you know it will be at least one row (C56), then you could use

```
Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Range("C56"), Sheet1.Range(C1000).End(xlUp)).Value = 0
```

That starts in row 1000 and goes up until it finds something. So if your data goes from C56:C200, that's the range that would be cleared. You would have to have all blanks between the end of your data and row 1000.

You could also use xlDown, but if you only have one row, it gets a little trickier.

**Edit**

You have text interspersed in the numbers, so you'll have to loop through the cells and only change the ones you want. For example

```
Sub test()
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    
    For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("C56:C350").Cells
        If IsNumeric(rCell.Value) Then
            rCell.Value = 0
        End If
    Next rCell
    
End Sub
```

There may be better tests than using `IsNumeric`, but that would depend on the nature of your data. Always make a backup before trying any code you get from the internet.

Comment: Hi Dick, thank you very much for your answer ! 
I had actually already used the formula:
Sheet1.Range("C56:C350").Value = 0

The issue is: I want to set C56:C69 to 0 but then C70 is a text, and I want to keep it. Then C71:C78 to 0 but C:79 is a text that I want to keep etc.. Therefore, I was wondering if it existed a formula that would just put the number value as 0 but keep the text values untouched.

Comment: Did you actually try the suggested code?

Comment: Hi, my bad, wrote it wrong.. It works now, thank you very much ! I added a condition to exclude empty cells to:
Sub SetAllMediaValueToZero()
Dim rCell As Range
    
    For Each rCell In Sheets("Indexation parameters").Range("C56:C350").Cells
        If IsNumeric(rCell.Value) And Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
            rCell.Value = 0
        End If
    Next rCell
    
End Sub